# How would I constantly position a point above a ray?

Tags: trigonometry

my Vector math skills aren't top notch so I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem.

I have a ray that goes from point [a, b] and I need a point to constantly be above that line by an offset of 2. So if the ray is directly horizontal the point will increase by 2 in the y direction, and if the ray is completely vertical they point will increase by 2 in the x direction. How could I accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ky9kszy07c. 

I think you want something like this?

Comment: Imagine you rotate the ray counterclockwise from horizontal to vertical position. How would you like the point to behave when you reach the vertical position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can compute the normal line of the line that travels from $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$ and then travel 2 units along the normal line.

First, verify that $$y=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)+y_1$$ travels through $A$ and $B$. Then the normal bisector is given by

$$y=\frac{x_1-x_2}{y_2-y_1}(x-\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})+\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}$$

So what we can do is travel 2 units along the normal bisector for the desired result. That may include solving a kind of ugly looking system of equations.

We want a point that is on the normal line and is also on the circle centered at 
$(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2})$ with radius $2$. I drew a picture of this in desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ts12vjjknh.

[image]

We can find this point by solving the system of equations given below. Sorry for the change in notation in the equations below $(x_1,y_1)=(a,b)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(c,d)$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, like this. I understand how to get the center of the circle, but I can't figure out how to get the location of the point.

Comment: You could try and solve the system of equations. The point needs to satisfy the equation for the circle and the normal line simultaneously.

Comment: I seemed to have solve this issue slightly. I added 90 degrees to the angle of inclination then added the 2 * sin(newAngle). It doesn't interact in the x direction exactly how I need yet though.

Comment: after looking at your desmos after the edit. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your response!